# Command line tools to view process list in Windows 10. pslist slow

Tags: windows-10, command-line, process, process-explorer

Default *Task Manager* and [Sysinternals ProcessExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) are well-known GUI applications to show processes details in Windows 10. I use both.

Windows 10 comes also with command-line `tasklist.exe`.
It shows the processes list and but I can not make it show them in *tree mode*.
From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269165/viewing-the-process-tree-tlist-tasklist) I tried with `/SVC` with no luck.

Just downloaded [Sysinternals PsTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) which come with `pslist.exe` & `pslist64.exe`.
This one seems to be that tool I want, since it can show all processes in tree mode.
It is like a command-line *ProcessExplorer*.

The only problems is that `pslist` takes a lot of time to show the results.
As a comparison, `tasklist.exe` takes less than 3 seconds to show all the processes.
Whereas `pslist` (both exes) take about 26 seconds, either showing or not as tree.

Why is `pslist` so slow?
Are there other alternatives?

Comment: probably because it is gathering much more information. Maybe use the S switch?....Figure 5 on this page....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc162490(v=msdn.10)

Comment: I have never seen such delays: on my Win10 Pro system, `pslist -t` shows 220 processes - it runs in 770ms. I suggest you use other SysInternals utilities, such as ProcExp or ProcMon to find out what `ps list` is doing for such a long time.

Comment: @Moab Switch `-s` seems like work as Unix `top` command, and does not really help here.

Comment: @AFH I have run ProcMon, with a filter for `pslist64.exe`, but I do not know where to start... I can see a *Process Start* at 16:07:37.2231183, and *IRP_MJ_CLOSE* at 16:08:08.9720484. There are 10,876 events... I can see tons of RegOpenKey/QueryValue/CloseKey, but also many IRP_MJ_CREATE/CLEANUP/QUERY_SECURITY/CLOSE and FASTIO_ACQUIRE/RELEASE_FOR_SECTION_SYNCHRONIZATION/NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN/QUERY_INFORMATION... The information is overwhelming... 
BTW, mine shows 317 processes.

Comment: I exported `ProcMon` info to a CSV file, and got a total of 10876 events with the following returned codes:
TOTAL:10876, SUCCESS:7410, NAME NOT FOUND:2022, BUFFER, OVERFLOW:421, FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS:396, FAST IO DISALLOWED:336, ACCESS DENIED:182
, NO MORE ENTRIES:46, REPARSE:38, PATH NOT FOUND:14, INVALID PARAMETER:5, IS DIRECTORY:4, BUFFER TOO SMALL:1, NAME INVALID:1

Comment: Are there any events with long delays before the next event, in particular network accesses? I log ~16K events, but they all occur within a couple of seconds (`pslist` runs a bit slower when monitored).

Comment: I am getting this type of event: 
IRP_MJ_:3023, FASTIO_:2356, RegQuery:2034, RegOpen:2056, RegClose:377, RegEnum:940, RegSet:11, RegCreate:2, ProcessProfiling:31, LoadImage:32, ThreadCreate:6, ThreadExit:6. Let's see if I can find any delay...

Comment: Most of the events are run in the same second, but at the end, following 4 Operations are repeated 96 times, which is what is causing a delay of 31 seconds : 
`"RegQueryKey","HKLM","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegCloseKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib","SUCCESS",""
"RegQueryValue","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\Disable Performance Counters","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 20"`
*Should I remove that Registry entry?*